# how to rebind META key from esc to option key?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm new to emacs. I want to rebind the META key [in the Terminal.app on OSX] from esc to the option key. What should I do to make that happen?

Comment: Have a check on here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93874/changing-the-meta-key-in-emacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use alt/option key as META key:

1. Open terminal
2. Go to preferences
3. Go to Keyboard
4. Select "Use Option as meta key"

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .emacs

```
(if (eq system-type 'darwin)
    (progn
      (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)))
```